# Using Bloodhound %QUERY token multiple places

Tags: typeahead.js, bloodhound, bootstrap-tags-input

I'm using [bootstrap-tags-input](/questions/tagged/bootstrap-tags-input) [typeahead.js](/questions/tagged/typeahead.js) and [bloodhound](/questions/tagged/bloodhound) to implement some tagging functionality on a site I'm working on.

I'm using "remote" to get data from an OData endpoint I've made and I'm using the `$filter=substringof('%QUERY', Description)` token in the url to find items that contains what a user writes in the tagging field.

In my datasource I return 3 properties; `Id`, `Description`, `ExternalId`.
Right now the only property I'm searching for results in is `Description` but I would like to search through `ExternalId` as well as those 2 properties are displaying in the suggestion dropdown.

I've tried doing like so:

```
/odata/EquipmentResult?$filter=substringof('%QUERY',Description) OR substringof('%QUERY',ExternalId)
```

I've inspected the requests using Fiddler and it shows that only the first `%QUERY` is actually changed into the search text while the other `%QUERY` does not change into the search text.

Is there a way I can add `%QUERY` in my url multiple times to also include `ExternalId`?

Answer (score 1):

I also found this issue, here is my work around:

```
        remote: {
            url: "/odata/EquipmentResult?$filter=substringof('%QUERY',Description) OR substringof('%QUERY',ExternalId)",
            replace: function (url, query) {
                return url.replace(new RegExp('%QUERY', 'g'), query);
            }
        }
```